# Powershell can't find fzf binary in path

Tags: powershell, fuzzy-search, oh-my-posh

I have an issue with my PowerShell. Everytime I launch my PowerShell Terminal I get this error.

```
    Exception: C:\Users\user\.config\powershell\user_profile.ps1:23
Line |
  23 |  Import-Module PSFzf
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Failed to find fzf binary in PATH.  You can download a binary from this page:
     | https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/releases

Set-PsFzfOption: C:\Users\user\.config\powershell\user_profile.ps1:24
Line |
  24 |  Set-PsFzfOption -PSReadlineChordProvider 'Ctrl+f' -PsreadlineChordRev …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The 'Set-PsFzfOption' command was found in the module 'PSFzf', but the module could not be loaded. For more
     | information, run 'Import-Module PSFzf'.
```

I saw that there is an Issue on GitHub and they suggested to install it again. I did it with

```
Install-Module -Name PSFzf -RequiredVersion 2.4.0
```

But this could not fix the problem. You guys are my last chance I didn't find anything and I don't know what is expected to put in the PATH.

Maybe you guys faced the same problem and could help me.

Best Regards

Knome

Comment: [Download pre-built binaries for Windows. `fzf` is also available via Chocolatey and Scoop](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#windows).

Answer (score 0):

Download the [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) and then Extract it. Further Copy the fzf.exe file to C:\Windows\System32.
Finally, close and start a new shell.
It works for me.